# How can I check the "additional sections" of vim-airline in greater details?

Tags: plugin-airline

I use vim-airline but the content of the "additional sections" on the status bar of the vim-airline are cut off due to the limited space of the window.

[image]

The space is too tiny to include the last section. The message seems to be "tr(ailing...)" or something like that. But is it possible to check the message, possibly by running a command (e.g. `:AirlineCheckAdditionalSection`) on the command mode?

Answer (score 1):

You don't see the full message if you maximize the window containing Vim? Because I don't believe that section is "hard" truncated so if you have the screen real estate widening the window should reveal the messages.

But maybe you're on a small device and that's not an option. I'm not aware of a direct way to reveal the text other than changing screen geometry but based on the vim-airline help one should be able expose it indirectly. But I've not been able to get the commands to do anything. Maybe you'll have better luck.

The first idea is to set the truncation width for all other sections to small values. Something like this...

```
let g:airline#extensions#default#section_truncate_width = {'a': 5, 'b': 5, 'x': 5, 'y': 5, 'z': 5, 'warning': 80, 'error': 80 }
```

('warning' and/or 'error' are the sections that are cutoff for you)

Alternatively, one should be able to make room by hiding most of the other sections...

```
let g:airline#extensions#default#layout = [ [ 'a' ], [ 'error', 'warning' ] ]
```

Revert to default layout with:

```
let g:airline#extensions#default#layout = [ [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ], [ 'x', 'y', 'z', 'error', 'warning' ] ]
```

In any case what you are missing is most likely one or both of these:

```
[X]trailing
[X:Y]mix-indent-file
```

The first indicates that you have trailing whitespace on at least one line. The second indicates that you have both tab and space indentations in the same file. `X` and `Y` will be line numbers. I'm pretty sure they represent the closest occurrence(s) of the relevant state as the numbers change depending on what line the cursor is on.

I don't recall seeing anything but those two warnings.

Comment: Thanks and yes I'm on 12' MacBook with tmux splitted panes, and may have not enough window space...

Comment: Okay, well see if those airline commands work for you. BTW, if the tmux pane size is the difference you can maximize a pane with the toggle `prefix+z`...in case you didn't know.